# Why can’t you say “I fell the stairs”?

Tags: grammaticality, phrasal-verbs

The verb *to fall* strongly implies the direction *down*, but in some circumstances it is obligatory (in StdAmEng) to include the word “down.”  The example I have in mind right now is

> I fall *down* the stairs
>   * I fall the stairs

Formally speaking, what’s going on here?  Note that this is not the same as

> I fall [down] *[to/on/...]* the ground
>   * I fall [down] the ground

Here *down* is optional (it sounds a bit redundant to my ear, but neither option is wrong), and *[preposition] the ground* is a normal prepositional phrase.  In other words, I don’t think *down* is acting as a preposition in “I fall down the stairs.”

Comment: *Down* in the phrase *He fell down the stairs* is an adverb, as is *off* in the following: *She fell off her bicycle*. Although in both instances the person ends up on the ground, in the latter we don't normally say: "She fell down from her bicycle". Consider someone who *falls down on their knees*, you'd never say: "fall onto their knees".

Comment: Sure you would: "I fall on my knees to the Father of Jesus ..." from the Catholic hymn "Dwelling Place" by John Foley. Reference http://www.hymnary.org/text/i_fall_on_my_knees_to_the_father_of

Comment: @Mari-LouA I’m pretty sure that *off her bicycle* is a prepositional phrase, just as *from her bicycle* is.   You cannot otherwise account for the substantive following.  Consider “The spider fell off him”, for example.  The spider certainly did not fell him in an off direction; it fell from him.  If you construe *off* to be an adverb, you’re stuck with *fall* somehow becoming transitive (which it isn’t), or else you have an adverb that takes a substantive complement (and in the oblique case where available, as pronominally) — which is what we call a preposition.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**to fall down** is a *bipartite verb*. Loads of English verbs are bipartite, including:

- to throw out
- to pick up
- to fill in
- to see through
- to figure out
- to show off
- to go away
- to write up

These verbs all have distinct senses compared to the plain verbs.

*To fall* and *to fall down* have very similar meanings, but they are distinct. As [outis nihil](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/178655/why-can-t-you-say-i-fell-the-stairs#comment372451_178656) noted, 'to fall down the stairs' is very different to 'to fall on the stairs'. *On the stairs* is a locative adjunct, it is an optional phrase telling you where the action happened. *To fall* means that someone or thing that was standing collapsed under gravity. *To fall down the stairs* means that someone collapsed and tumbled down a stair case - they didn't collapse and stay on a single step. You can also fall down escalators and hills and Egyptian pyramids, anything you can tumble down! So while *to fall* is intransitive, *to fall down* is transitive.

If you're interested in reading more about bipartite verbs this is a good article (and where I got the examples from): [*The bipartite structure of verbs cross-linguistically, or Why Mary can't "exhibit John her paintings"* by Heidi Harley](http://ling.auf.net/lingbuzz/000435).

Comment: I tend to think that X-bar theory is complete bullshit -- by which I mean both that I don't for a moment believe that it describes any part of the actual mechanism used by the brain to process language, and that *as an abstract model* it's ridiculously impoverished, such that its adherents have to pile epicycles on top of it if they're serious about capturing real language phenomena.  That article is a beautiful demonstration of the latter complaint - the whole "this restriction to Germanic verbs isn't *really* a morphophonological constraint" nonsense most obviously... (1/2)

Comment: ... but I could equally complain about the tortured sentence structure diagrams on page one if I wanted ... *anyway*, leaving the analysis aside, the description of bipartite verbs strictly as phenomenon is well-done, and I like your answer to my original question a lot better than any of the others; it gets at *why* one construction is intransitive and the other not.  (2/2)

Comment: @Zack I don't care too much for syntactic theories these days, this just happened to be the one article on bipartites I'd already read. Still, I think there's good reason to analyse verbs as a light verb + a content-rich verb; lots of various semantic theories have things like CAUSE().

Comment: I used to hang with a bunch of construction grammarians; that theory has sort of the opposite problem, being too *flexible* (also, while I think it's not as bad as anything Chomsky's put out there, it too has at best only a handwavey connection to things neurons might plausibly be doing).  I do agree that the decomposition of (many) action verbs into method + consequence components seems like it has legs.

Comment: I think you are confusing *to fall down*, as in “Jane fell down when she sprained her ankle” with *to fall (**prepositional phase**)*, as in “And with that choice, John fell from grace and was never to recover.”  You can *fall in the bushes, fall to your knees, fall from a great height, fall down a chasm, fall between two opposing forces, fall before the throne, fall for a pretty face, fall inside a circle, fall out a window, fall outside the law, fall by the wayside, fall next to your dog, fall over a cord* — and many, many others, none of which mean *to fall down*, which takes no complement.

Comment: @tchrist I don't think you can 'fall down a chasm', that sounds odd  to me. I'd say 'fall into a chasm' instead. 'fall to your knees/fall before' is another idiom, as is 'fall for a pretty face'. I think you've got lots of closely related but distinct senses in those examples.

Comment: @curiousdannii People fall down wells and mine-shafts all the time. Unfortunately.

Comment: @tchrist they do. And those examples are definitely fine.

Comment: @curiousdannii around these parts, tchrist consistently speaks with great apparent authority from a profound and willful ignorance of modern linguistics.  Just ignore him.

Answer (score 6):

In English, an [intransitive verb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intransitive) is a verb that does not take a direct object.  "To fall" is quite simply an intransitive verb.  That's pretty much all there is to it.

Other intransitive verbs include "to go", "to happen" and "to run" (in the sense of quickly moving, as opposed to "to run" in the sense of operating a machine, or an organization).  It is not correct to say "I go market" because a preposition is required: "I go to market".  "I fell to the ground."

**ETA**: I'm racking my brain, Zack, trying to figure out how to give a more "complete" answer.  It is a matter of basic grammar.  Intransitivity means that the verb does not take a direct object.  That means that if it has an object at all, it must be indirect.  That's why the preposition is required: it signifies an indirect object.  It happens that many intransitive verbs pertain to motion, and for that reason the indirect object's prepositions tend to those that pertain to motion: to; up; down; and so forth.

Can you "fall the duck"?  Can you "run the sidewalk"?  That's what it would take to omit the preposition and pretend the verbs "fall" and "run" were transitive.  Do you not see that there is nothing further to say about it?

Comment: Great answer. I'd just add that "to fall down the stairs" means something different from "to fall on the stairs."

Comment: This doesn't seem like a complete answer to me.  It accounts for "I fell [preposition] the ground" and "\*I fell the stairs", but you haven't explained why "I fell *down* the stairs" *is* acceptable.

Comment: @Zack - Gravity. It's hard to fall _up_ the stairs. (Seriously, though, any preposition will work. For example, I might say, "I fell _off_ the stairs," if I took a misstep on a small set of stairs with no handrail, in the same way I could say, "I fell _off_ the stepladder." I could also say, "I fell _to_ the stairs, if I tripped over a skateboard in the basement and landed at the foot of the staircase. However, those are relatively rare cases; most of the time, when we fall _around_ the stairs, we are falling _down_ the stairs.)

Comment: As Terry Pratchett puts it, gravity is a hard habit to break.

Comment: +1 But You can say *I ran home*. To clarify your answer a bit, *down the stairs* is an adverbial phrase. *Stairs*, being a noun, needs a preposition to make it adverbial. *Home* has its own adverbial sense.

Comment: Zack and John, I can testify from direct personal experience that, gravity notwithstanding, it is, indeed, possible to fall _up_ the stairs. The situation: I fell while climbing stairs, but did not lose elevation, so did not fall "down" the stairs, and when I regained my feet I was two steps higher than where I fell.

Comment: @bib, *I ran home* includes an indirect object with the preposition omitted.  It is a special case, not an exception.  *I ran to home* is how it would be expressed, otherwise.

Comment: But you can run a course, or run a track.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist That is how I first thought about it. But numerous dictionaries list *home* as an adverb on its own. See, e.g., [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/home?q=home).

Comment: @bib, that's very interesting!  One learns something new every day, clearly!  Thanks!

Comment: @Robusto, yes you can "run a course" etc, but that is an idiom that defies the rule.  You really cannot run a course, you can along run *along* a course, just as you can run *along* a track.  "Run", no matter what you do, is still an intransitive verb in these two cases.  Or so I believe!

Comment: JR, accomplished klutz that I am, I once did fall up the stairs and broke a metatarsal.  I tripped on one step and fell face-first into the rest of the stairs.

Answer (score 1):

To "fell" something is to **chop it down.** As in "I felled a tree."

"Fell" is also the past tense of "fall." But even in this context, you can't talk about "falling" the stairs. You need a preposition, to fall **down** the stairs, or even to fall **from** the stairs.